How can I add an image in the header of Typora?
I am starting to use Typora and I want to put a logo image in the header. How can I do it?
I've tried to put the image text in the headers options like this ![image]() but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Use this Method: I think this method is useful for you
![Alt text](image_path)


This method only inserts the image in the body of the document, not in the header.

In CommonMark-compliant markdown implementation you can do:
# title ![](image.jpg)


This method only inserts the image in h1, not in the header.

you'll have to explain what you mean with header then. please update your question, otherwise we cannot help you.
